# Update a field on drupal commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I have a product field that takes a number as an input(quantity) and w sometimes this quantity becomes empty so I want with the module Commerce Feeds to update this field from sth to empty .But it keeps not updating the field with nothing(empty).

I might say  that I need to do it automatically and not manually

Comment: Are you sure you're matching the field mappings correctly?  For example, the id you use in your import file, etc is matched correctly to the nid and you have correctly identified the fields for the quantity input without any typos (also in the mapping settings)?  It's hard to know without more information on your setup and even version of Drupal what may be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

1. You may want to look into the commerce stock module. That's what you sound like your using this quantity field for. http://drupal.org/project/commerce_stock
2. Did you create this product via feeds? Feeds can only update items that are created with feeds.